# Find weight distribution in multiple term loss

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions, hyperparameter

I have a question if it is possible to find/learn the weight distribution in a multiple term loss where each weight models the importance of each term on the total loss.

```
total_loss = a*loss1+b*loss2+c*loss3
```

My question is whether it is feasible to consider those a,b,c variables as learnable parameters so the model learns the correct weight distribution or if the way to go is just like a hyperparameter random/grid search (learning rate for example) where you iterate through a number of predefined values.

Answer (score 1):

Making them directly trainable would not work, since the training algorithm could reach a trivial solution and simply minimize the loss by setting them to zero (or make them negative and then let your actual loss terms grow till infinity). However, you could take the Bayesian approach and introduce a prior over them—giving the model the freedom to find their optimal value while making it stick to some constraints that you define. In such case, your priors would be the hyperparameters that you would still have to set manually. Practically, you would add another loss terms, penalizing $a$, $b$, and $c$ for having some "unlikely" values.